# Usage of conditional constructions

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives, subordinate-clauses, conditionals, indian-english

I'm from India where English is not a native language. Generally here we use constructions like  "Should you work hard?" and "Had I done it?" in interrogative sense.

But now I find that they are also used in subjunctive conditionals. For example:

> "Should you work hard, you will pass."

> "Had I done it, I would not have repented."

Now my question is why interrogative form of construction like "Should you work hard" is used instead of "If u worked hard"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably assume that "should you work hard" is a question because the subject **you** and the auxiliary verb **should** are inverted. There are a few other situations where inversion can take place, and this is one of them.

**should** has several meanings, and one of them is used to express the possibility of a future event: see the POSSIBILITY meaning in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should). This meaning is very formal, and you are unlikely to hear it in everyday speech. It can be used in two ways:

> If you should need any help....
> Should you need any help...

Note that, in the form without **if**, the subject and auxiliary verb are inverted, but this does *not* make it a question.

The difference between "should you work hard" and "If you worked hard" is that the **should** version is talking about hypothetical future hard work, and the **if** version is talking about hypothetical current hard work or actual past hard work.

The same applies for your **had** sentence: see the final example in the HAVE meaning in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/had).

Answer (score 0):

> why interrogative form of construction like "Should you work hard" is used instead of "If u worked hard"?

Your two examples are not equivalent, because *Should you work hard?* is a complete interrogatory statement, and *If you worked hard [...]* is incomplete since it lacks the requisite conditional result. This leads us to the answer to your question.

The form *Should you work hard?* is used in order to avoid the necessity of stating the conditional purpose. When *if* is used to introduce a question, the conditional purpose must be included in order to employ standard English usage. For example, *If you worked hard, then would your family have food?*

The word *should* may be used to introduce a question because, as you have said, it can "express condition" (Merriam-Webster, [definition 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/should)). When you use it to form a question, as in *Should you work hard?* the usage implies a purpose *Should you work hard [if your family is to have food]?* (This also uses Merriam-Webster's *should* definition 2: "to express obligation".)

The word *if* can introduce a question, when it explicitly states the purpose that a "should" interrogatory merely implies. To repeat the previous example: *If you worked hard, then would your family have food?* This is because *if* can mean "on [the] condition that" (Merriam-Webster, [definition 1d](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if)), and thus it can also be a conditional, just as *should*. Usually, the structure is an *if...then* (interrogatory) statement